# Can't install msi package, asking for .Net framework 4

Tags: c#, .net, msdeploy

I recently upgraded my system to Windows 7 Enterprise. I have created an install package for a console application built with .Net framework 3.5 in VS2010. But when I try to install the msi on an XP machine, it gives me this warning that .Net Framework 4 is required.

Steps I tried to resolve the error:

1. Right click on Project and set the Target Framework to .Net Framework 3.5 in Application tab.
2. Right click on Project, Select Publish > Prerequisites > a) Selected .Net Framework 3.5 SP1 and b) Windows Installer 3.1
3. Right click on Setup Project, Prerequisites > a) Selected .Net Framework 3.5 SP1 and b) Windows Installer 3.1
4. Rebuild Setup Project to create msi.

All my above steps are futile since I am still getting a warning when I am installing the msi on an XP machine.

Has anybody got better idea to resolve this issue?

Comment: Is your installer built in .Net 4?

Comment: No it's built with .Net 3.5 only. I have also checked all the dependencies too, they are all also build with 3.5 only.

Comment: Is there any specification in your setup project indicating .Net4 as prerequisites ?

Comment: @SidAhmed, there is no such thing for .Net 4 as prerequisite

Comment: It depend on what you use to build your setup project, for example, if you use InstallSield (I'm not sure what version), it exist.

Comment: What happens if you run your msi on a Windows 7 machine without .Net Framework 4.0 installed?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet. Can give it a try but I am guessing it will result in same error.

Comment: Most likely you will get the same error (although you will rule out that it has anything to do with it being an XP machine).  A tool I used a lot some years ago when I worked with mis files was Orca (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/255905).  Try using it to look for .Net 4 references.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think I have found the solution to this problem.

Right click on Setup Project > View > Launch Conditions. Over here, it was already referring to .Net Framework, Right click on it > Properties, change the version to .Net Framework 3.5. It solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Install the full .NET Framework 4 on your XP machine

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17851

Comment: Why installing the .Net 4 while the solution is built using .Net 3.5 ? If he wish to install the solution in other clients machines, you suggest that he install the full .NET4 every time ? I do not agree

Comment: I too don't agree with it. I can't force a user to install .Net 4 on his machine.

Answer (score 0):

Dee you need to eliminate a few things. try constructing a 'blank' msi project with no dependencies in the manner described above and see if the resulting MSI requires .net4 on the target machine?

Secondly, **what warning are you getting that .net4 is required?** is it just the help link redirecting you to the generic .NET download page? if so, you can change this link to point to .NET3.5 SP1 specifically.

Comment: thanks for the approach. I will do that. For your second point, when I try to install the msi on an XP machine, it shows a warning that msi can't be installed because it needs .Net Framework 4. It asks me to manually install .Net Framework 4. Besides, I already have .Net Framework 3.5 SP1 installed on my XP machine.